# WebClient builder call from one microservice to another microservice giving bad request error for first time in Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, webclient, spring-webflow, spring-webclient, spring-reactive

We are making use of WebClient Builder call for communication among micro services in our project.It's springboot-thymleaf-webflux based application.Everything is running fine till now but we got a requirement from Client to change GET call to POST call in thymleaf controller.After making these changes at UI and Backend,Thymleaf calls are working fine but one of the XHR i.e post call from UI-- is giving bad request error for Webclient call to second microservice for first click and working for second click.I compared header and request for both click did not find any difference.I am not able to understand why webclient behaving abnoramlly first time and working fine second time. Below is code snippet for webclient call and it is routing to WebclientResponseException without hitting to second microservice by saying BAD Request for http://second-microservice -eureka-address/endpoint-url

````
     * Submitting xyz 
     * @param submitFlowRequest
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<ApiResponse<SubmitResponse>> submitFlow(SubmitFlowRequest submitFlowRequest,
            Map<String, String> headers) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String uri = propertyConfig.getAggregationService()
                + propertyConfig.getAggregationSubmitCCInfoURL();
        DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(uri);
        factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.URI_COMPONENT);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> clientHeaders = buildHeaders(headers);
        return webClientBuilder.uriBuilderFactory(factory).build().post()
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(clientHeaders)).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .syncBody(submitFlowRequest).retrieve().bodyToMono(ApiResponse.class)
                .onErrorMap(ConnectException.class,
                        error -> new VzwRuntimeException(ErrorCodeEnum.V404.toString(), Constants.OPP_TC_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                                (Constants.CONNECTION_FAILURE_TEXT + Constants.AGGREGATION)))
                .onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class,
                        error -> new VzwRuntimeException(ErrorCodeEnum.V404.toString(), Constants.OPP_TC_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                                (Constants.CONNECTION_FAILURE_TEXT + Constants.AGGREGATION)))
                .flatMap(res -> {
                    Audit apiAudit = Audit.builder().apiUrl(uri).request(LoggerUtil.asJson(submitFlowRequest))
                            .response(LoggerUtil.asJson(res))
                            .executionTime(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
                            .headers(LoggerUtil.asJson(clientHeaders)).transactionType(res.getData()!=null?mapper.map(res.getData(), SubmitResponse.class).getTransactionType():"").build();
                    LoggerUtil.logExternalApiCalls(apiAudit);
                    return Mono.just((ApiResponse<SubmitResponse>) res);
                });
    }```

Please provide me some lead.I am tired of finding solution for this.
````

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue with Netty. Netty holds some connections with invalid state HttpObjectEncoder. When client gets such connection from a pool and uses it to make request to a destination server, it immediately fails because DefaultHttpRequest cannot be encoded by HttpObjectEncoder.
Disabling connection pool fixes the thing.